# SPSS Median, Average- In between P5 and P95

Tags: spss

I do have SPSS dataset, and need the P10,P25,Mean, Median, P75, P90 values by excluding the below P5 and above P95 values.
Below image Column E is my Original Data and my Median value is $322.10

### Calculated P5 & P95 in E1 and E2 cells. Now, have excluded the values with Lessthan P5 and above P95 numbers. After this math, I got my value is $398.11. So, I want to perform such calculations in SPSS. Please suggest. I usually run the numbers by using the below SPSS syntax. Now I want to add this condition in my existing syntax.

Q1.1 [MINIMUM, PTILE 5, PTILE 10, PTILE 25, MEAN, MEDIAN, PTILE 75, PTILE 90, PTILE 95, MAXIMUM, VALIDN F40.0]

[image]

Comment: You didn't post your SPSS syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

To identify the cases that belong to P95+ or P05- you can run:

```
rank vars=yourvar /ntiles(20).
```

This will create a new variable in which every case is marked with it's (5%)Ntile. (you can change the treatment of ties when dividing the cases to Ntiles - look up `rank` command for that).
Now you can filter out the cases you don't want in the data and then run your analysis again:

```
select if not any(Nyourvar, 1, 20).
freq yourvar /format notable /ntiles=4 /ntiles=10 .
```

NOTE: using `select` will delete the unwanted cases completely.
if you want to delete them only temporarily for one analysis you can use the command `temp.` just before running the above lines. If you want to remove them temporarily but for a few analyses look up the `filter` command to use instead of `select`.